# Enter a variable x many times in the same line Python

Tags: python

I am working on a project and I need the program to get an input X, then ask for the input again X many times all in the same line. You probably don't understand but here is an example:

input x: 3                                                                                   ;input y: 123 456 789

i tried using this, but it doesn't work obviously:

```
for i in range(m):
    [x[i]*i] = map(int, input().split())
```

any help?

Comment: please give an example

Comment: In the example you have 2 different inputs, can you elaborate on the desired behavior

Comment: This isn't very clear, are you trying to insert 3 numbers to `y` and verify there are 3 numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the approach suggested below:

```
x = int(input("Enter number of times: "))
y = input("Enter " + str(x) + " input params: ")

data = y.split(" ")
if len(data) != x:
    print("Wrong number of params")
else:
    result = list(map(int, data))
    print(result)
```

First, you enter all input required and then you can check if the number of integers inserted in`y` is equal to `x` in order to proceed. This is just a demonstration of an alternative way and you can adapt it to your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC Try:

```py
x=int(input())
y=[]
for i in range(x):
    y.append(input())
#if you want y to be single string with all the inputs delimited by space:
y=" ".join(y)
```